# Wrong gps timestamp in Android with only 7 digits

Tags: android, gps, timestamp, location

I've an app that uses the LocationManager in Android and i'm tryng to get the current time provided by gps in millis.

I noticed in my database a row with a wrong timestamp.
There's others that are always corrected, for example:

- 1477050084629: Correct time provided
- 6406148: Incorrect time provided

The incorrect time is provided by using a device Samsung SM-J105B (Galaxy J1 Mini Dual Chip).
I didn't find topics related a problem like this, only problems when the time is different by hours or days.
In my case the timestamp return a number of small quantity of digits.

Comment: `I noticed in my database a row with a wrong timestamp`. That is the wrong place to look for errors. You should check values before you put something in a database.

Comment: Yes, should've checked for errors before inserting in the database. But I trusted the return of gpstime was always correct. My question is about why in some cases it returns a time so different from the others.

Comment: Maybe it does not. Maybe something went wrong while inserting in the database.  Who knows? You really should check right away. It should be 13 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem would be generated by device, see this topic:

https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/articles/216515918-My-Activity-has-the-wrong-date-

Comment: Pietro Cândido
May 19, 2016 15:43

Comment: On the commentary of Pietro Cândido May 19, 2016 15:43, it said he had same the problem with the same device. I think it's a problem with this specific model. In other models the problem don't happen. I will add a treatment in my code for that situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a bigint  column.  Ask yourself is one bit not set on a binary number?  Look at the code that uses that column then look specifically how the value is passed in code is it serialized when it's passed to your code?  Check if the value is converted to and from human readable timestamps.